# Join two data tables in MYSQL and avoid duplicate values

Tags: mysql

I created two tables using MYSQL, tblorder and tblitem.

```
CREATE TABLE `tblorder` (
`orderId` int NOT NULL,
`orderName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`orderId`)
```

[image: tblorder]

```
CREATE TABLE `tblitem` (
`itemId` int NOT NULL,
`itemName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`itemUnit` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
`itemRate` double NOT NULL,
`orderRef` int NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`itemId`),
 KEY `fk1_idx` (`orderRef`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`orderRef`) REFERENCES `tblorder` (`orderId`)
```

[image: tblitem]

I tried to join the two tables using query below

```
SELECT orderId,orderName, itemName, itemUnit,itemRate
FROM tblitem 
INNER JOIN  tblorder on tblorder.orderId = tblitem.orderRef
```

Now result show like Image-01

[image: Image-01]

How to remove duplicate values in orderId ,OrderName columns in result table?
Thanks to help me to solve this problem.

After joining tables is it possible to get output like below?
[image: Final output]

Comment: Either receive all shown rows (they're unique) or use some criteria which allows to select one row per grouip and ignore all another rows.

Comment: Add `GROUP BY` statement, if you would like to join rows by some parameter.

Comment: In your one single row where orderId is "1" and orderName is "Order 1" what should be in itemName, itemUnit and itemRate?

Comment: @MarkB, In item table I have Ordered items for any Order.

Comment: You do not have an `ORDER BY` clause in your select statement so, in your one single row where orderId is "1" and orderName is "Order 1" what should be in itemName, itemUnit and itemRate?

Comment: Answer for this question is available in below link.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/287746/join-two-tables-in-mysql-and-avoid-duplicate-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for this question is available in below link. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/287746/join-two-tables-in-mysql-and-avoid-duplicate-values

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sortId = 1 THEN CAST(orderId AS CHAR(10)) ELSE '' END AS 
orderId, CASE WHEN sortId = 1 THEN orderName ELSE '' END AS orderName, 
itemName, itemUnit, itemRate
FROM
(
SELECT orderId, orderName, itemName, itemUnit, itemRate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
(PARTITION BY orderId ORDER BY itemId) AS sortId
FROM
(
    SELECT orderId, orderName, itemName, itemUnit, itemRate, itemId
    FROM tblitem 
    INNER JOIN  tblorder 
        on tblorder.orderId = tblitem.orderRef
) orderItems
) orderItemsSorted
ORDER BY orderItemsSorted.orderId, orderItemsSorted.sortId
```